# Elastic beanstalk health turns severe

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an Elastic Beanstalk application, uploaded my built code and it went into the process. Only to show that the health is severe. I don't know why is this happening. It works well if I create the environment with sample application. But not when I choose to upload my code. Can anybody help me out why am I getting this error?
I'm using Node.js

Here is the error log.

[Error log gist](https://gist.github.com/toseefAhmed-pk/f95a2ca28e1d4d4faaa2654a0e2eb590)

Comment: "Can anybody help me out why am I getting this error?" No, because this is just a symptom of the actual error, which would be in your application's logs or the EB deployment logs or something, which you haven't provided in your question. Or perhaps your application simply doesn't respond to the health check requests or something. The level of information you have provided so far is entirely insufficient for anyone to provide any help at all.

Comment: Apologies for being a rookie. I have uploaded the Log info. Please check if you can find  it. I have added the link in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the log `/var/log/nginx/access.log`, Elastic Beanstalk tries to make a `GET` request to your application under the path `/`. This request fails with a return code `502 - Bad Gateway`, i.e., your application is not working correctly:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

When you look at the log file of your application (`/var/log/web.stdout.log`), you will see these error messages:

```
sh: ts-node: command not found
[nodemon] failed to start process, "ts-node" exec not found
```

Your node application fails to start since it cannot find `ts-node`.

It seems that you try to run typescript code on the Elastic Beanstalk, which only supports javascript out of the box. Please have a look at [this medium article](https://medium.com/quick-code/how-i-automatically-deployed-typescript-to-elastic-beanstalk-to-speed-up-server-development-22b89870e159) how to automatically compile your typescript to javascript. For test purposes, you can also compile locally on your machine and then upload the javascript.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I quite didn't understand that. Can you be a little more brief?

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed In your question, you have linked log files ("Here is the error log. Error Log"). This link is not working anymore and says "Access Denied". Probably you have still access, but we don't. Only once you provide us with the log messages again, we can help you. Maybe paste them somewhere outside AWS or on a public S3 bucket so that they are not lost again.

Comment: I have pasted the logs in a gist. Please check link in the original question

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed With the help of the log files, I was now able to find your problem and updated my answer.